# What's best way to handle DropDownListFor in Asp.Net MVC 3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have this controller:

```
public ActionResult Novo()
{
   var products = context.Product.Select(x => new SelectListItem
   {
      Text = x.Name,
      Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Id).Trim()
   }).ToList();

   MyViewModel myViewModel= new MyViewModel()
   {
      Products = products
   };

   return View(myViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Novo(MyViewModel myViewModel)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         ...

         context.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      } else {
         var products = context.Product.Select(x => new SelectListItem
         {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Id).Trim()
         }).ToList();

         MyViewModel myViewModel= new MyViewModel()
         {
            Products = products
         };

         return View(myViewModel);
      }
}
```

I must to populate Products in ViewModel in this two methods.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
   public string ProductIdSelected { get; set; }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductIdSelected, Model.Products)
</div>
```

The problem is in my Controller, i must to populate ViewModel in this two methods. I don't like that, I don't like to create a method to populate ViewModel too because when validation fail, the others fields keeps populated, why my Products fields don't keeps populated too? I think using a method is ugly. Is there a way to avoid to use another method?

Is there a way to populate Producs in my ViewModel only once and cache the list of Products when someone do a Post and the Post is not valid.

If NOT, the better way is to use another method. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't like to create a method to populate ViewModel too." So what you're saying is that you don't like reusable code?

Comment: @Acaz - If you don't want to use a method (which I think is the right choice), you're going to have to store the data *somewhere*. You could cache it (not guaranteed to be there on post-back), you could serialize it somehow and use a model binder to re-load from the value providers. However, I think this is over-analyzing the problem. Just use a method... it's integral to C# :)!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. What do you expect to happen when validation fails? What do you mean by "when validation fail, the others fields keeps populated, i think this is too ugly."

Comment: @Dismissile - I think he's saying that the *other* properties are loaded (because their values are found via the value providers), but the drop down list isn't loaded because only the selected IDs are returned (standard form posting...).

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568808/how-do-i-generate-a-select-list-from-database-values/6569443#6569443 it discusses the same concern

Comment: see update. Ok, using a method is the better aproach actually? If yes, i will using that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with creating a separate method to populate your VM (for the GET and for the `POST` when validation fails)?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Novo()
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
    this.LoadProducts(myViewModel);
    return View(myViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Novo(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ...

         context.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else 
    {
         MyViewModel myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
         this.LoadProducts(myViewModel);
         return View(myViewModel);
    }
}

private void LoadProducts(MyViewModel model)
{
    model.Products = context.Product.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Id).Trim()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Additionally, you could provide another parameter for `LoadProducts` so that it could set the selected item.